# SQLite3 installation and usage in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sqlite

I seek some clarifications regarding the installation and usage of `SQLite3` in Ubuntu (e.g. Ubuntu Lucid). It seems to me that, to install it, one just need to download the precompiled binary from here: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html, save it in some directory, and **use that binary** to create a `.db` file. Then that's it. Of course, for real-world usage, I'm mostly reading/writing from/to it through its Python driver in my code: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite.

A few questions:

1. Is the above a correct way of installing SQLite3 in Linux systems?
2. I also see two packages installed on my system: `libsqlite3-0` and `libsqlite3-dev`, which are of different version from the latest binary. Are these the ones that actually get used when I read/write from/to the `.db` file through the Python driver?
3. What is a correct way of upgrading SQLite3? Do I just grab the latest precompiled binary from sqlite.org, and start using it to access the existing `.db` file?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu-specific installation and belongs to http://askubuntu.com/